# Couple of page layout problems

Tags: php, html, css

I'm having some trouble getting my page laid out the way I want.  I have a gap that's showing up between two divs on my page, and a css menu that I can't figure out how to center.  Any help would be appreciated...

FYI, template_header.php is the only template with any content in it at this point.

[image: http://i216.photobucket.com/albums/cc125/rcarp711/Forum%20Pics/PHPproblem.png]

Here is the code...

*** index.php ***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body >
        <?php include './templates/template_header.php'; ?>
        <div id="pageBody">
            <?php 
                include './templates/template_contextmenu.php';
                include './templates/template_content.php'; 
                include './templates/template_sidebar.php';
            ?>
        </div>
        <div id="pageFooter">
            <?php include './templates/template_footer.php'; ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

*** template_header.php ***

```
<div class="banner" >
    <img class="bannerImage" src="./graphics/FullLogo2.png" height="216" />
</div>
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="products.php">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="info.php">Information</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

*** style.css ***

```
header, footer, aside, nav, article, section  {
    display: block;}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;}

div.banner {
    background-image:url("./graphics/BannerBG_220.png") ;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    height:13.5em;
    border:solid;
    border-width:thin;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;}

.bannerImage {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;}

#menu{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height:2.25em;
    font-size:1.25em;
    font-weight: 500;
    background:transparent url(./graphics/navbackground2.png) repeat-x ;
    font-family:Arial,Verdana,Helvitica,sans-serif;}

#menu ul {
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    width:auto;}

#menu ul li {
    display:block;}

#menu ul li a {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    color:#e5e5e5;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #3d3d3d;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: .4em 1.5em .2em 1.5em;
    height: 2.25em;
    background:transparent url(./graphics/MenuDivider.png) no-repeat top right;}

#menu ul li a:hover, #menu ul li a.current {
    background: url(./graphics/NavBackgroundOn.png) repeat-x;}
```

Comment: you should just throw all of that code into a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: nice read for your menu-problem: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/beautiful-css-centered-menus-no-hacks-full-cross-browser-support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to center #menu using margin: 0 auto without a width. You can measure the width of the links with javascript and then set the sum of all link widths as the width of #menu. You'll see a short delay but it'll work.

As for the white gap, an inspection with Firebug will show you where the unwanted margin or padding is coming from.

Comment: It's not correct, that the menu can't be centered without a width. (ref: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/beautiful-css-centered-menus-no-hacks-full-cross-browser-support)

Comment: @Yoshi: Thanks for correcting me and posting that link. I've upvoted your comment updated my answer so that it's hopefully correct.

Comment: Thanks loads, you two. This information is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the whitespace around your php tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body >
    <?php include './templates/template_header.php'; ?>
    <div id="pageBody"><?php 
            include './templates/template_contextmenu.php';
            include './templates/template_content.php'; 
            include './templates/template_sidebar.php';
        ?></div>
    <div id="pageFooter"><?php include './templates/template_footer.php'; ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

To center it, try this in the css:

```
  #pageFooter { margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; }
```

Comment: You could actually comment out everything after the template_header.php include, as that's the only include that is actually adding anything at this point. The other include files are empty. Everything is happening in template_header.php at the moment.